# How can I make this jQuery play nice with browser "back" buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm not very good at jQuery or Javascript in general, but I've managed to cobble together something. Please bear with me, and forgive my ignorance.

[FIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/g30j3ckd/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#searchResults tr').click(function (event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
    }
});

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("active");
    }
});
});
```

Basically I've set up some jQuery that will allow users to click anywhere in a table row, to select the check box in the first column of that row. And when the box gets checked, it adds a css class to the whole row. It also works in reverse, unchecking the checkbox, and removing the css class. Works great so far.

Where this fails is when someone selects a few rows and then submits the form, thus navigating to the next page in my website, but then realizes they've made a mistake and they hit the browser back button to get back to this table with their selections. When someone does that, the browser restores the checkboxes correctly, but the css classes are not set for those rows. So it ends up looking like this:

[FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/g30j3ckd/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchResults tr').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Box is checked, but the row isn't highlighted like it should be.

I'm sure they're some simple jQuery way to search for checked checkboxes on page load, and apply the css at that time, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways

You can loop through table data to check which input is checked and add the class

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/v6xebjsw/

**Code**

```
$("td").each(function() {
 if ( $("input[type='checkbox']", this).is(":checked")) {
$(this).closest('tr').addClass("active");
  }
});
```

You can also use find for what is checked using the tables id

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/taoza74x/

**Code**

```
$("#searchResults").find(":checked").closest('tr').addClass("active");
```

But the easiest way is to simply use a selector for input checked

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/9uggkcxy/

**Code**

```
$("input:checked").closest('tr').addClass("active");
```

or use the `has` method

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/4h12v3tn/

**Code**

```
$("tr").has("input:checked").addClass("active");
```

the code can be this way too

```
$("tr:has(input:checked)").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That bottom option worked perfectly. And now that I see the solution, it's painfully obvious.

Comment: @KMurphy no probs,  ive added another way that's using  the has method.